# Get posts by category and language, using PolyLang

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, polylang

I'm creating a plugin and I already could get the posts by category and by the current language using get_posts() function from WordPress and passing the attribute lang with the pll_current_language() from PolyLang.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 6,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'lang'             => pll_current_language()
);
return get_posts($args);
```

Now, I'm wondering how to get the posts by categories related to the language?
For example, I have the News category for English and Noticias for Spanish. How can I set this automatically?

Something like this:

```
$args = array(
    ......
    'category' => **current_category_for_this_language**
    ......
);
return get_posts($args);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **pll_get_term** and filter by category. In this case '34' is my term ID (gotten by hovering the edit link of the term).

By the way as far as I know get_posts gets only posts in the current page language by default and it gets posts by default sorted by date DESC, so you could omit those from your query I think.

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page'   => 6,
  'category'         => pll_get_term(34)
);
return get_posts($args);
```

**Sources**

https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/

> **pll_get_term**
>
> Returns the category (or post tag) translation
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> pll_get_term($term_id, $slug);
> ```
>
> ‘$term_id’ => (required) id of the term you want the translation
>
> ‘$slug’ => (optional) 2-letters code of the language, defaults to current language

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

> Default Usage
>
> ```
> <?php $args = array(
>   'posts_per_page'   => 5,
>   'offset'           => 0,
>   'category'         => '',
>   'category_name'    => '',
>   'orderby'          => 'date',
>   'order'            => 'DESC',
>   'include'          => '',
>   'exclude'          => '',
>   'meta_key'         => '',
>   'meta_value'       => '',
>   'post_type'        => 'post',
>   'post_mime_type'   => '',
>   'post_parent'      => '',
>   'author'       => '',
>   'author_name'      => '',
>   'post_status'      => 'publish',
>   'suppress_filters' => true 
> );
> $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
> ```

Comment: Couldn't be better explained! Thanks a lot, Joris!

Comment: Great solution, it helped me a lot for a custom taxonomy

`'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-slug', 'field' => 'term_id', 'terms' => pll_get_term(34)))`